# Could not communicate with the VM agent for snapshot status" using Azure backup

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have tried to backup my azure VM using azure backup vault.

I have followed below link

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/backup-azure-vms/

After creating backup vault I got below error when I initiate an initial backup

---

Could not communicate with the VM agent for snapshot status. Snapshot VM sub task timed out.

Please see the troubleshooting guide on how to resolve this.

Job ID: 088764b3-3ba9-4e5c-a606-67333327d790
Start time: Tue May 03 2016 13:02:17 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
EndTime: Tue May 03 2016 13:37:57 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
Geo: West Europe
Resource ID: 9092441375884970642

### Activity ID: 8e8294af-5940-4985-bd99-bb06f32cbe4b-2016-05-03 12:02:16Z

I tried to troubleshoot the problem  followed below links

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2014/04/07/install-the-vm-agent-on-an-existing-azure-vm/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/vm-agent-and-extensions-part-2/

I am still getting the same error message.

Anyone can help me with this?

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: @Patrick I'm also having the same issue. Please let me know if you figured something out!